# Declaration of a public variable in a php class

Tags: php, class

could someone explain to me if php classes has the equivalent of

```
Class name
{
  Public:   <----- this bit
    string variable;
    int another;
    bool athird;
}
```

or do you have to declare public variables in php as

```
Class name
{
  public $variable;
  public $another;
  public $athird;
}
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Have you done any research? [E.g. reading the PHP documentation on OOP?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981375/setting-public-class-variables

Comment: Please read the PHP documentation and find out yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare multiple variabes at once, seperated by a comma:

```
class name{

    public
        $cat = 'cat',
        $dog = 'dog',
        $hamster;

    private
        $login_message = 'blah',
        $other = 33;
}
```

Comment: My apologies. Yes I have read the php documentation and wouldn't ask such a basic question if the answer was as easy to find as that. The documentation makes no reference to public: nor my multiple reference books or google. I understand the mechanics behind public declaration, but was looking for the more blanket approach that public: gives and hoped for a more positive response that being treated like a schoolboy looking for answers to his homework. On a positive note, thank you Steve for your multiple declaration answer, this is probably as close as I'm going to get.

Comment: @frogtag i think the negative reaction was down to a misunderstanding. Im guessing you where refering to the feature in c++, hence my answer with the closest you will get in php, but others might not have made this connection

Comment: @frogtag Also, if this answer is of some help to you, please mark it as correct