# How can I use the value of variables defined inside a php class in another page

Tags: php

I'm fairly new using PHP classes, I have done some PHP using the procedural method for a while but never fully done proper object oriented programming on php. Which brings me to my question:

I have one file called classes.php where I intend to define all my php classes. Inside that file I have created a class as follows:

```
require_once("connection.php");

class User
    {

        public function getUserInfo() {
            $userinfo = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='". $_SESSION['username'] ."'");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userinfo)) {

                // USER DETAILS:
                $userid = $row['id'];
                $username = $row['username'];
                $userfirstname = $row['first_name'];
                $userlastname = $row['last_name'];
                $useremail = $row['email'];
                $useraddress1 = $row['address_line_1'];
                $useraddress2 = $row['address_line_2'];
                $userpostcode = $row['postcode'];
                $userphone = $row['phone'];
                $usermobile = $row['mobile'];
                $usercreated = $row['created'];
                $usermodified = $row['modified'];
                $useraccess = $row['access_level'];

            }
        }

    } // end of User
```

Now I want to use the values of the variables defined in that class in another page. But how can I access those values?

So far I'm trying this (unsuccessfully):

```
<?php
include "php_includes/classes.php";
$user = new User();
?>

<div class="somediv">
    <?php echo $user->getUserInfo($username) ?>
</div>
```

I have also tried:

```
<?php
    include "php_includes/classes.php";
    $user = new User();
    ?>

    <div class="somediv">
        <?php echo $user->$username ?>
    </div>
```

Is there any way to echo those variables in another page so I can use the user information in, for example, profile pages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use php session

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass variables between two PHP pages without using a form or the URL of page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778425/pass-variables-between-two-php-pages-without-using-a-form-or-the-url-of-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should return the value from function.

require_once("connection.php");

```
class User
    {

        public function getUserInfo() {
            $userinfo = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='". $_SESSION['username'] ."'");
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userinfo);

            return row
        }

    }
```

and now only have to show the detail of user

```
<?php
  include "php_includes/classes.php";
  $user = new User();
 ?>
 <div class="somediv">
    <?php $user_detail=$user->getUserInfo(); ?>
    <label>name:</label><br>
    <?php echo $user_detail["first_name"]; ?>
 </div>
```

Hence you can check whether row is null or not and whole array can be returned by this function of class any where this class included in file.

Comment: Hi Muhammad, I have tried this but I get a few errors. I think the class is not recognising the value of `$con` my connection.php code is `<?php
session_start();

$depth = "";

include $depth."constants.php";

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DATABASE);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

?>` and it works fine cause everything else in the site works, including the login and logout procedures.

Comment: public function getUserInfo() { global $con;
        $userinfo = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='". $_SESSION['username'] ."'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userinfo);    

        return row
    } this will resolve the issue becuse conection variable is out side the class so make global to acces in the class of function

}

Comment: Muhammad, that has actually worked! Thanks for your answer

Comment: This is the final code I have used in the class:
`<?php 

$depth = "../";
require_once("connection.php");

////////////////////////////////////////////
 
 
class User
{
 public function getUserInfo() {
  global $con;
  $userinfo = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userinfo);
  return $row;
 }
 
} // end of User

?>`

Answer (score 0):

Before your function you need make PUBLIC VARIABLE like:

```
public $userid;
```

Then next in code in function you need to use:

```
$this->userid = $row['id'];
```

**EDIT**

Your calss need to be:

```
class User
    {

        public $userid;
        public function getUserInfo() {
            $userinfo = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='". $_SESSION['username'] ."'");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userinfo)) {

                // USER DETAILS:
                $this->$userid = $row['id'];


            }
        }

    } // end of User
```

And you also need include this class file in other php page when you want show data.

Comment: Hi Robert, I have formatted the class as you have suggested. But how do I call the variable values in the other page? I'm trying this with no success: `<?php echo $user->username ?>`

Comment: Do you get any error or ? I will edit my answer with full class look and you see its ok in your code.

Comment: Just for test, try  $this->$userid = $row['id']; change with  $this->$userid = 'test'; and tall me if test print (with that you will sure that is problem with class or else your database not give to you any record and your variable was empty).

Comment: No, still not printing on the page

Comment: You can check it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981375/setting-public-class-variables

Comment: Right, I have defined the variable OUTSIDE the while loop with the test value like: `public $userid = "test";` and it prints on the page. But when the value is being defined inside the while loop, it doesn't print on the page. So if I declare the empty variable outside the loop like `public $userid;` and then grab the value inside the WHILE loop like `$this->userid = $row['id'];` or even `$this->userid = 'test';` it doesn't work

Comment: Its problem with your SQL query because your result was empty and while loop not started by event of row. You can try outside the while loop test if you $_SESSION['username'] are good, try this OUTSIDE the wile loop
$this->userid = $_SESSION['username']; 
if you don't get any result your $_SESSION['username'] is empty and not working.

Comment: Hi Robert, I can't define it cause it keeps giving me a syntax error "unexpected T_VARIABLE. I'm defining it like this: `$this->username = $_SESSION["username"];` if I define it inside the loop it doesn't give a syntax error, but still doesn't print

Comment: Just try this, in sql query change  $_SESSION["username"] with real user in your database, and you back $this->userid = $row['id']; inside the while loop and if you get result your session variable was not work.

Comment: Its also problem with your database connection, do you have any other mysql query (witch you are 100% sure that your mysql connection work)?

You can also start chat.

Comment: Yes the connection works cause I'm pulling information from the database on the page without using the class, I can login and logout using that connection code and the $_SESSION['username'] variable is being used outside the class without problems. In regards to chat, it won't let me because I'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: Sure robert, i have compiled all the relevant files here, but changed all sensitive information.  https://lux365.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/php_class_issue.zip

Comment: You don't need public def. of variable if you use it in just one function or other, try remove $userinfo and $con from public definitions.

Comment: Hi Robert, I have actually tried Muhammad's answer and it is now working using his approach. I do appreciate the time you have taken on trying to find a solution as well. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare the variable as **PUBLIC**

```
class User
{
       public function getUserInfo() {
       $userinfo = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='". $_SESSION['username'] ."'");
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userinfo)) {

                        // USER DETAILS:
                        public $userid = $row['id'];

        }
        }
}
```

For more information check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)