# Access a class within a function

Tags: php

Using as an example the class defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981375/setting-public-class-variables)

```
class Testclass {
    private $testvar = "default value";
    public function setTestvar($testvar) { 
        $this->testvar = $testvar; 
    }
    public function getTestvar() { 
        return $this->testvar; 
    }
    function dosomething()
    {
        echo $this->getTestvar();
    }
}

$Testclass = new Testclass();
$Testclass->setTestvar("another value");
$Testclass->dosomething();
```

I would like to add inside a function "one more value", like this:

```
function test_function() {
    $Testclass->setTestvar("one more value");
}
```

But it doesn´t work. I gives the error message undefined variable Testclass. In order to make it work, I have to define the variable as global within the function, like this:

```
function test_function() {
    global Testclass;
    $Testclass->setTestvar("one more value");
}
```

I am quite new to PHP, but it seems rather strange to me this way of using it. From the main PHP file it´s already defined, but when I use it from a function I have to define again.Basically what I am trying to do is to create a class that creates a new file and adds strings to it from different functions.  Is there not a better way? Any suggestions? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: See [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use singleton

MyClass::getInstance()->doSomethingUsefull();

Sometimes you can use static method

MyClass::doIt();

Comment: Thanks Ivan for you fast answer! Seems quite a good way using singleton, but I continue to have the same problem using it.  If you could give me some complete code example it would be of great help! (or at least a few more hints)

Answer (score 0):

Functions have their own private variable scope. So (for example) you can use `$i` in a function without worrying about it screwing up another `$i` somewhere else in the program. If you want to have a function perform actions on an already-existing object, just pass the object as a parameter to the function:

```
function test_function(Testclass $testclass)
{
    $testclass->setTestvar("one more value");
}
```

Then call it with your object:

```
$Testclass = new Testclass();
test_function($Testclass);
```

Note: If the functions you're defining outside the class are tightly related to the class, then you probably want to define them as methods inside the class instead of separate stand-alone functions.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I do understand the concept of the private variable scope. I am not worried about screwing up another variable somewhere else in the program, it´s the opposite. I want to use the same class already defined. The class is a logfile. I create a log file and then just add lines to it. From the main program it works great, but from inside a function I have to add _Global_ and define again the variable, which looks quite strange to me. Just wondering if there is a better way. I though me message was well explained.